# Spring webflow unit test with spring security on

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I'm trying to test a webflow controller with spring security on:

```
<action-state id="search">
    <secured attributes="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
...
</action-state>
```

I'm using `AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests` subclass.

Now, the test runs ok without the "secured" tag (I don't make any mocks for the security), but once I add the security tag, the test keeps finishing with success, although I anticipate a security exception to be thrown.
Any ideas why it doesn't work and how should I configure it?
Thanks in advance!
Igor

Comment: Could you please post a snippet with "secured" tag?

Comment: Well, it's in the message... I'm using it inside the action-state in the webflow. It works fine when I actually RUN my app, but it fails in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution: I needed to add a securityListener manually.
Before `startFlow`:

```
setFlowExecutionListener(getSecurityListener(new String[] {"ROLE_ADMIN_FAKE"}));
```

Where

```
private FlowExecutionListener getSecurityListener(String[] roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String role: roles) {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
        result.add(authority);
    }
    Authentication auth = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("Igor", "", result);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    return new SecurityFlowExecutionListener();
}
```